# Java: FasterXML / jackson deserialize array without keys

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

Is there a way how to deserialize JSON array

```
{["a", "b", 1]}
```

into following Java class

```
class MyObject {
  private String firstItem;
  private String secondItem;
  private int thirdItem;
}
```

using [FasterXML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) **jackson-databind**?

I only found answers where there are *key: value* items in the array.

Comment: You can't deserialize JSON like that It will take it as Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `{["a", "b", 1]}` is not a Valid Json Array (or JSON) .... JSON Array would look like this `["a", "b", 1]`

Also you could deserialize the Json Array into a Java Object by writing a Custom Deserializer for the Java Object and Register it with Object Mapper using Module in Faster Xml.

Check the Following Link to get more Info on How to write Custom Deserializers

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

**Still I would suggest not using Array Representation for an Object.**

Comment: Thanks. It's not me who is representing the object this way :-).